# Divide a number recursive

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
public function divideNbPlay($nb_play){
    if($nb_play % 400 !== 0){
        $nb_play = divideNbPlay($nb_play % 400);
    }
    return $nb_play;
}
```

I want to get the rest of division, for example if I have

```
nb_play = 590, I want to return 190
nb_play = 806, I want to return 6
....
```

Comment: That's exactly what your code is already doing?

Comment: Why do you need recursion for this?

Comment: @PeeHaa, I don't understand

Comment: Neither do I OP. Neither do I.

Comment: It can be done without recursion ?

Comment: What / where / how / why does the recursion requirement come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use `divideNbPlay` function inside the function. `Modulus` operator return remainder of divided.

```
function divideNbPlay($nb_play){
    $nb_play = $nb_play % 400;
    return $nb_play;
}

$nb_play = 806;
echo divideNbPlay($nb_play);
```

Answer (score 1):

No need all of that you already have the answer.

```
function divideNbPlay($nb_play){
    return $nb_play % 400;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't require recursion to get the result you want. Here is the solution which output the result:

```
<?php
function divNum($num) {
    return $num%400;
}

echo divNum(590);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you **really, really, really** want to have a recursive solution for this, you shall not use the % operator, but use the minus operator instead.

What you have to do is recursively subtract 400 from the $nb_play, until the remainder is below 400. You can return the remaining value.

Example code (not tested):

```
public function divideNbPlay($nb_play){

    $nb_play = $nb_play - 400;

    if($nb_play > 400){
        divideNbPlay($nb_play);
    } else {
       return $nb_play;
    }
}
```